# str.match ignoring blank values

Tags: python, pandas

when i'm trying to use str.mtach on blank values it is simply ignoring the blanks all together.

Before I resort to using an If statement, I want to see if I can get some help figuring this one out.

```
df={'Original Litigation':['yes','','','',"No"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df["Suit Filed (Y/N)"]=""
df["Suit Filed (Y/N)"][df["Original Litigation"].str.match("Yes|Y|represented|Open|Closed",case=False)]='Yes'
df["Suit Filed (Y/N)"][df["Original Litigation"].str.match("N|No|''",case=False)]='No'
```

I did find a way to get what I want using an if else statement. However the issue is I would still have to go back, and look through all the values that were mapped to 'No'. Where if I were able to get the above working, I would only have to filter for the blanks to see what values need to be added in the str.match.

Comment: Why did you put "''" when you're trying to match an empty string?

Comment: I tried df["Suit Filed (Y/N)"][df["Original Litigation"].str.match("N|No|',case=False)]='No' and everything gets mapped to "No"

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regex pattern `^$` (beginning-of-string followed by end-of-string)
to match empty strings:

```
mask = df["Original Litigation"].str.match("N|^$", case=False)
df.loc[mask, "Suit Filed (Y/N)"]='No'
```

or, alternatively, you could use `str.len` to measure the length of the strings:

```
s = df["Original Litigation"]
mask = s.str.match("N", case=False) | (s.str.len() == 0)
```

---

For example,

```
In [311]: s = pd.Series(['a','','c'])

In [312]: s.str.match('a|^$')
Out[312]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Note that the regex pattern `N|No` will match anything that begins with an `N` or begins with `No`. Since `No` begins with `N`, the pattern `N|No` is equivalent to `N` -- the `No` is not necessary. Similarly, `Yes|Y|represented|Open|Closed` can be reduced to `Y|represented|Open|Closed`.

---

By the way, notice that there are two sets of brackets (`[...][...]`) in

```
df["Suit Filed (Y/N)"][...] = 'No'
```

This is called chained-indexing and should be avoided when making assignments in Pandas since in some situations [such an assignment may fail to modify `df`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

The right way to code this in Pandas is to use `loc`:

```
df[mask, "Suit Filed (Y/N)"] = 'No'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you. Would you happen to know why l df["Suit Filed (Y/N)"][df["Original Litigation"].str.match("N|No|',case=False)]='No' does not work? I dont understand why its mapping everything to 'No'

Comment: `N|No|` tells `match` to match `N` or `No` or... nothing. Nothing always matches.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks unutbu.